# How do I find out which version of Sensu I am using on linux box?

Tags: sensu

Is there a command I can type in linux that will show the current version of Sensu that is installed?

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg -s sensu` worked for me (linux, used apt-get to install)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned how you installed it or on what kind of OS you are so this might be a very general answer.

In CentOS/RHEL family OS you can use `yum info sensu` provided that you used yum to install it.

In Ubuntu you can use `dpkg -s | grep <pkg_name>`